# How write a recursive print program

Tags: c, recursion

Gurus,

I want to know how to write a recursive function that prints

1 
12
123
1234
...
......

For eg: display(4) should print

1
12
123
1234

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int n)
{
        if(n != 0)
        {
                print(n-1);
                printf("\n");
                print(n-1);
                printf("%d",n);
        }
}
int main()
{
        print(3);
}
```

Output

1

12

1

123

### Issues

I wanted to write a **pure recursive** *(without any loop)* function but unable to filter unwanted prints.
Hope someone will help me out!!!

### Update

Thanks all for the answers.From all the comments which were given it seems like we can write one with only recursion and a loop is required.

Comment: You will find in future @Manu that you will get much more help if when you ask a question you can show that you have first tried to do something yourself in code - possibly posting some example of code you have that does not work. As it is your first question here it might be good to read the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: simply put:  [What Have You Tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: @Manu - To reopen a question, after you've updated and fixed the reasons it was closed for then "flag" it for moderator attention. Mark it as other and explain why it should be reopened.

Comment: @Manu Will you accept to have two functions, or does it have to be one single function?

Comment: @lc - It has to be a single recursive function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To define a recursive function, you have to do three things:

1. **Define what the function does.** In this case it is printing numbers from 1 up to *n*.
2. **Define what the recursive call is.** What happens the next time around? The easiest way is to think from the bottom up; in this case, on each earlier line, it is printing numbers up to one less than the previous. Therefore, every time you call the function again, you want to call it with one less than the previous number.
3. **Define your stop condition.** When should I stop recursing? In this case, once you hit the number 1, this will be your last iteration. This means, we want to call the recursive function *until* this stop condition is reached - or in other words, *while* n is greater than 1.

Therefore, we end up with the following algorithm:

```
function display(n):
    if(n > 1):
        display(n-1);

    print 1..n;
```

Comment: @logoff No, it's not C; it's an algorithm in pseudocode. It's also not give-me-teh-codez, either; it's an explanation. And a rather good one I believe, especially given the OP only gave a problem description.

Comment: @logoff It is not C but it **is** recursive

Comment: @lc., OK, but the question is tagged as C. I'm only pointing it.

Comment: It is more important to understand what he is explaining than it is to just get the code written for you.  You have to put SOME effort in. Try it out, try some code then look for help. This isn't your own homework page.

Comment: @RossC You seem to have mistaken logoff for the OP.

Comment: Arrgh IE 7 and my stupidity have caught me out. My apologies to @logoff for that.

Comment: @logoff Work.... they use IE 7. The goggles do nothing! Hopefully updating soon. We'll be dragged kicking and screaming into the 20th century: IE 8 ha.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: OK, I improved my answer with the guidelines of @lc.

```
void print_recursive(unsigned int num) {
    if (num > 1) {
        print_recursive(num - 1);
    }
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
        printf("%d ", (i + 1));
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: It works by looping, not recursion as asked for. That is why I have given -1

Comment: @logoff Also to be honest your comment "Next time try something yourself" is pretty rude particularly as it is his first question asked here. If you do not want to help the OP don't help.

Comment: @mathematician1975 you need to try something, then show your problems or difficulties. if not, it seems a not solved school/university exercise.

Comment: @logoff what are you trying to say here?

Comment: @mathematician1975 I'm trying to say that you need to provide a try or something like that, not simply asking a question to get the response. for instance, code that doesn't solve your problem, but you don't know why.

Comment: @logoff You seem to be confusing me with the poster of the question I think.

Comment: @mathematician1975 Or perhaps logoff understands English and is using the generic "you".

Comment: that's obvious, thank you @JimBalter. I was talking in general, not to you mathematician1975.

Comment: And ironically, RossC really did (and rather rudely) confuse logoff with the OP in the comments to lc.'s answer.

Comment: You shouldn't print the space after %d ... that doesn't produce the requested output.

Comment: that's true @JimBalter. but if the code prints numbers with two digits, it will help. anyway, I think it is not important.

Comment: Actually, it is important that SO answers produce the output requested in SO questions, but I suppose less important when the question has been closed (inappropriately, in this case).

Comment: What i want to achieve is the output with PURE (read as, not with loops) recursion.

Comment: @Manu you need a loop my friend... if you can print a sequence without looping call me!

Answer (score 1):

This question is quite old, yet **none of the answers answer the actual question**, viz. solving the problem in C using recursion only, without explicit loops.

Here is a simple solution obtained by fixing the misunderstanding present in the original code (confusion between two possible functions of "print"). There are no explicit loops.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void countto(int n)
{
        if(n != 0)
        {
        countto(n-1);
        printf("%d",n);
        }
}

void triang(int n)
{
        if(n != 0)
        {
                triang(n-1);
                printf("\n");
                countto(n);
        }
}

int main()
{
        triang(4);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We keep calling PrintIt() with the argument-1 recursively until x < 1. Each call will then return in reverse order when x < 1. At each return we print a line starting at 1 to x.

```
#include "stdio.h"

void PrintIt( int x )
{
    int i;
    if( x > 1 )
    {
        PrintIt( x - 1 );
        printf("\n");
    }

    for( i = 1; i < x+1; i++)
    {
        printf("%d", i);
    }

    return;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    PrintIt( 4 );
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The last line is printed without a newline.

Answer (score 0):

The recursive function used here is func(int).
Initially the value is passed from the main() program. 
The recursion occurs till we reach the exit condition , which is val=0 in this case.
Once we reach that level , we move the penultimate frame a print "1". The same pattern is followed to attain the sequence "1 2". . . "1 2 3 " . . . "1 2 3 4"

```
int func(int val){

        int temp,i;

        if( val == 0 )
        {
                val++;
                return val;
        }
        else
        {
                val--;
                temp=func( val );

                for (i=1;i<=temp;i++)
                {
                        printf("%d",i);
                }
                printf("\n");

                temp++;
                return temp;
        }
}

int main(){

        int value=4, result;

        result=func(value);
}
```

Comment: Rather than only post a block of code, please *explain* why this code solves the problem posed. Without an explanation, this is not an answer.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thnx for the comment. I've tried to add an explanation

Comment: I dont want loop in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, here's a purely recursive solution. It's in python, which is practically pseudocode anyway. (Non-pythonic newlines are for clarity).

```
def loop(max, row=1, col=1):
    if col <= row:
        print col,
        loop(max, row, col+1)
    elif row < max:
        print "\n",
        loop(max, row+1, 1)
    else:
        print "\n",
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_num(int x);
int n;
void main(){
printf("Enter number of lines: ");
scanf("%d",&n);
print_num(1);
}
void print_num(int x){
int i;
for(i=1;i<=x;i++){
printf("%d",i);
 }
if(x<n){
printf("\n");
x++;
print_num(x);
 }
}
```

This is simple, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
void display(int k)
    {
         if (k < 1) { return; }
         display(k-1);
         for (int i = 1; i <= k; i++)
         {
         cout << i;
         }
         cout << endl;

    }


    int main()
    {
        int a = 4;
        display(a);
        return 0;
    }
```