# How write a program which print recursively

Tags: c, recursion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How write a recursive print program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12890621/how-write-a-recursive-print-program)

I have already asked this question, but it was closed because of insufficient information.
[How write a recursive print program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12890621/1746220)

Gurus,

I want to know how to write a recursive function that prints

1 
12
123
1234
...
......

For eg: display(4) should print

1
12
123
1234

### Code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int n)
{
        if(n != 0)
        {
                print(n-1);
                printf("\n");
                print(n-1);
                printf("%d",n);
        }
}
int main()
{
        print(3);
}
```

Output

1

12

123

### Issues

I wanted to write a pure recursive function but unable to filter unwanted prints.
Hope someone will help me out!!!

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta- Its not the duplicate, its the "Clone" by the same user :-)

Comment: @Manu- That question is closed because the question was not standard. Have you even looked at the solution given there???

Comment: It's just an automatically inserted comment, @Abhineet. Agreed that it's a repost by the same user.

Comment: The question should not have been reposted, but it also shouldn't have been closed ... the OP provided "what have you tried" code when it was requested.

Comment: I hate these questions about "recursion". Some weeks ago it was a different task with a bit more printing and a "counting" function which didn't count anything, but it's essentially the same task. Is this really how programming is teached nowadays?

Comment: @stefan just for fun I looked at the Codecademy course on recursion in Javascript last night.  It has the same problem :(

Comment: Since the other one was closed it was reposted. What i want to acheive is the output with PURE (read as, not with loops). All the solutions provided where with loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May this be what you want?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void print(int n)
{
    int i;
    if (n > 0)                  // [2]
    {
        //call print recursively
        print(n-1);             // [3]
        for (i=1; i<=n; i++)    // [4]
            printf("%d",i);
        printf("\n");
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // If no argument, default to 8
    int value=8;
    if (argc > 1 )
        value = atoi(argv[1]);
    print(value);                // [1]
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it and execute like this:

```
display 3
```

or without any argument (which defaults to `display 8`):

```
display
```

The trick is to call `print(n-1)` before printing the output for the current `n`. This is the program flow when executed as `display 3`:

```
<main() function is running>
main() calls print(3) in [1]
   <print(3) is running, n is 3>
   since n>0 in [2] print(3) calls print(2) in [3]
      <print(2) is running, n is 2>
      since n>0 print(2) calls print(1)
         <print(1) is running, n is 1>
         since n>0 print(1) calls print(0)  
            <print(0) is running, n is 0>
            since n=0 print(0) doesn't print anything and returns
            now the function that called print(0) (that is, print(1)) takes over
         <print(1) is running, n is 1, continues executing in [4]>
         print (1) enters the for loop, prints "1\n" and returns
         now the function that called print(1) (that is, print(2)) takes over
      <print(2) is running, n is 2, continues executing in [4]>
      print(2) enters the for loop, prints "12\n" and returns
      now the function that called print(2) (that is, print(3)) takes over
   <print(3) is running, n is 3, continues executing in [4]>
   print (3) enters the for loop, prints "123\n" and returns
   now the function that called print(3) (that is, main()) takes over
<main() is running>
main executes return(0) and exits
```

This is what gets printed to the console:

```
1
12
123
```

If you move `print(n-1)` after `printf("\n")` you will have:

```
123
12
1
```

Comment: fail - you forgot to ensure that negative answers don't cause an infinite loop...

Comment: Thanks, replaced if(n != 0) with if(n > 0)

Comment: What i want to achieve is the output with PURE (read as, not with loops). Here the loop is used for achieving the output.

Comment: Thanks Jaume. I was able to understand the above code. But my original question was whether we can write the program without a 'for' loop? From all the answers i think it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for this.

```
#include<stdio.h>

    void rec_print(int n)
    {
     int i=1;
     if(n>0)
     {
      rec_print(n-1);
      for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
            printf("%d",i);
      printf("\n");
     }
    }

    int main()
    {
     int n=5;
     rec_print(n);
     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please don't just throw code at beginners. Explain. (Actually, never give a code-only answer on StackOverflow. It may solve the problem, but it never does _answer_ the question)

Comment: @stefan : I am beginner too .. won't do it again.. thanx for advice